# CakePHP : Get Table with many conditions

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, request, conditional-statements

I have a very specific problem. Even with the great CakePHP doc, I still don't know how to fix my pb.

I'm currently web developping using the CakePHP framework. Here is my situation :
I have a Table "TableA" which contains parameters "name", "type"(1 to 6) and "state"(OK and NOT OK) . What I want is getting all the Table lines which are type 5 OR 6 and which have not a same name line with "state" OK.

There are different lines of the table which have the same "name". I'm interesting to the lines from the same name where there is no OK state.

For example, there are :
name : example1   state : NOT OK
name : example1   state : NOT OK
name : example1   state : NOT OK
And there is no example1 with the state OK and this is this kind of line I want to get.

I would like to do this with the cakePHP syntax, with conditions in the TableRegistry::get function.

Thanks for helping. Waiting for your return.

PS:
What I achieved now is not the best solution :

```
$tablea_NOTOK = TableRegistry::get("TableA")->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    array('TableA.type' => 5),
                    array('TableA.type' => 6),
                ),
                'Etudes.state' => 'NOT OK'
            )
        ));
        $this->set(compact('tablea_NOTOK'));

        $tablea_OK = TableRegistry::get("TableA")->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    array('TableA.type' => 5),
                    array('TableA.type' => 6),
                ),
                'Etudes.state' => 'OK'
            )
        ));
        $this->set(compact('tablea_OK'));
```

And then in my view, i compared each line of the tablea_OK with the tablea_NOTOK. But there is a lot of data so the code is not perfect and slow

Answer (score 0):

You may consider creating a view table in your database which holds the combination of data needed.  Since the data will all be from a single table, you wouldn't need to loop through the data and compare it.

I don't know all your table relationships, but I made a simple table with these fields and data:

id name type state

1   Harry   5   OK

2   Harry   6   NOT OKAY

3   Harry   6   NOT OKAY

4   John    5   NOT OKAY

Then I wrote a query which would group by name and count the state values:

```
SELECT `name`, `type`, `state`,
(SELECT COUNT(state) FROM TableA as TableA1 WHERE `state` = 'OK' AND TableA.name = TableA1.name) as okay_count,
(SELECT COUNT(state) FROM TableA as TableA2 WHERE `state` = 'NOT OKAY' AND TableA.name = TableA2.name) as not_okay_count
FROM TableA
GROUP BY name;
```

The results look like this:

name type state okay_count not_okay_count

Harry   5   OK  1   2

John    5   NOT OKAY    0   1

You can adjust the query as needed and create your database view table and then call that in CakePHP.

```
$my_view_table = TableRegistry::get("MyViewTable")->find('all');
```

You can learn more about MySQL view tables [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx)